# stty command hangs when one end of the console cable is not connected to the telnet console server

Tags: telnet, busybox, stty

I am trying to boot my linux machine, and in the rcS file I have few stty commands…

```
stty erase ^H
stty intr “”
stty intr ^C
```

The first two commands are at the very beginning, and third one is much later to re-enable the interrupts (I am disabling the interrupts using stty intr “” in the beginning to prevent the user from interrupting the bootup process) so when the 1st command executes, my machine hangs during bootup.

IMP: I am running this command on a server which I can access through telnet as well by connecting an RJ45 cable to it, so when one end of the cable is connected to my machine and another end is kept hanging, i.e., connected to machine but not connected to telnet server, I am experiencing this issue in such cases only.
Also, as soon as the cable is connected back, the bootup resumes from there.

I am experiencing this while using unshielded cables, and if I plug in a shielded cable with same config as explained above, no bootup hang is seen. I checked the signals received from unshielded cable, it is transmitting some noise/erroneous signals which are misinterpreted by my machine in some way.
While its true that there is a hardware issue as well if erroneous signals are picked up by my machine, but if I remove these stty commands, the bootup doesnt hang even if only one end of cable is connected.

I have tried googling but it is not helping at all.
I am using BusyBox v1.31.1.

Any help is much much appreciated. Thank you.